# SQL JOIN one-to-many but don't repeat previous joins

Tags: sql

I need to create a join between two tables of companies on the **COMPANY_NAME** column (as there are no other common keys to join on). Subsidiary companies with the same name can exist in the tables.

The tables with the relevant data look like this:

**Table A**

```
ROW_ID | COMPANY_NAME        | REG_ID  ...
-------+---------------------+--------
1      | ABC UK LTD          | 992
2      | ABC UK LTD          | 221
3      | BOBS BAKERS PLC     | 109
4      | BOBS BAKERS PLC     | 234
5      | BOBS BAKERS PLC     | 677
6      | ADAMS ESTATE AGENTS | 309
```

**Table B**

```
ROW_ID | COMPANY_NAME        | CH_REF  ...
-------+---------------------+--------
4656   | ABC UK LTD          | AE/002
7986   | ABC UK LTD          | X0294
8748   | BOBS BAKERS PLC     | F9998
9820   | BOBS BAKERS PLC     | P2944
10233  | BOBS BAKERS PLC     | L00091
14346  | ADAMS ESTATE AGENTS | XM/122
```

I would like to end up with a query result that matches one-to-one on the **COMPANY_NAME** but doesn't duplicate the join on rows already matched. It doesn't matter about the sequence of the join, as long as all joins are unique. For example:

**Ideal query result**

```
A.ROW_ID | B.ROW_ID | A.COMPANY_NAME      | B.COMPANY_NAME      | REG_ID | CH_REF
---------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+--------
1        | 4656     | ABC UK LTD          | ABC UK LTD          | 992    | AE/002
2        | 7986     | ABC UK LTD          | ABC UK LTD          | 221    | X0294
3        | 8748     | BOBS BAKERS PLC     | BOBS BAKERS PLC     | 109    | F9998
4        | 9820     | BOBS BAKERS PLC     | BOBS BAKERS PLC     | 234    | P2944
5        | 10233    | BOBS BAKERS PLC     | BOBS BAKERS PLC     | 677    | L00091
6        | 14346    | ADAMS ESTATE AGENTS | ADAMS ESTATE AGENTS | 309    | XM/122
```

Can this be achieved in one SQL query? I would like to try to avoid having to keep iterating on the same dataset to achieve all the matches if possible.

Comment: (I know this ask is horrendous for many reasons, but grateful for any suggestions nonetheless!)

Comment: Do you know you'll always have the same number of a specific name in both tables? That is, if you have 3 of Bobs Bakers in Table A you'll have 3 Bobs Bakers in Table B? And what DBMS (name and major version) are you using, "SQL" covers a lot of systems and a task like this can be easier if you can use proprietary features.

Comment: Why do you want for `ABC UK LTD` `992;AE/002`, but not `992;X0294`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your sameple data each table has a given order from Row_Id so you can create a surrogate key for each using row_number() and use that for joining:

The following is compatible with most modern RDBMS.

```
with A as (
    select *, Row_Number() over(order by row_id) rn
    from tA
), B as (
    select *, Row_Number() over(order by row_id) rn
    from tB
)
select 
  a.ROW_ID "A.Row_Id", b.ROW_ID "B.Row_Id",
  a.COMPANY_NAME "A.COMPANY_NAME",
  b.COMPANY_NAME "B.COMPANY_NAME",
  a.REG_ID, b.CH_REF
from A join B on A.rn = B.rn;
```

Comment: Be warned that if for any reason the 2 tables did not always have each company name entered in both tables in the same order and the same number of times or if a row can be removed from one table without removing it from the other, this will break spectacularly.

Comment: Which  why I caveated it with working for the example data, for which it would have been easy to include a mis-match of rows or describe it as possible if it was. It can still be catered for though; there's been no feedback from the OP since asking the question.

Comment: @Stu you could partition by `COMPANY_NAME`, and include it in the join. That'll give more accuracy, but OP needs to specify more

Comment: In fact, you could just as well do a join on `COMPANY_NAME`, and `DISTINCT` the result. But OP seems to want something else

Comment: Yes that would keep company's aligned but could still be an issue with a mismatch of rows in either table, a full outer join might be what the OP would want in that case, but they need to add clarity if there are complications not documented - ie the tables might be in-sync via a trigger, we just don't know.